# insert picture without replacing the word in artist mode

Tags: artist-mode

I want to add rectangle outside the text as follows:

```
+---------+
|why there|
+---------+
```

But what I get is

```
+--------+
|hy there|
+--------+
```

I use C-c C-a r at the beginning of line which just above the character "w"